# How can I update position of an existing table (with points) in PostGIS using coordinates from another table but by specific ID?

Tags: sql, database, geolocation, postgis

I have a point geometry layer that were moved and not falling where it should be. I have the same version of the table with correct position and would want to use this to update table in my database.

I do not want to delete the points and insert again was hoping I can use the update functionality. I know its the `wkt_geom` field I need to update but no idea how to write my script.

```
UPDATE poles
SET wkt_geometry = st_geometryfromtext('POINT(long.lat)',4326);
```

I get an error about `wkt_geometry`.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get your log and lat

this example gets the same id and concats it to a point

```
Select CONCAT("POINT(", item_id, " ", item_id,")") into @point From items Limit 1;
Set @o_point := ST_GeomfromText(@point,4375);
Select ST_AsText(@o_point) as wktvalue,@o_point as punkt,@point;
```

Returns

```
wktvalue    punkt                                   @point
POINT(1 1)  FxEAAAEBAAAAAAAAAAAA8D8AAAAAAADwPw==    POINT(1 1)
```

You have of course adept the first select to get your own long and lat
and you have finally

```
UPDATE poles
SET wkt_geometry = @o_point;
```